# OrientDB GraphDatabase: OSQLSynchQuery for @RID to get graph.getVertex(rid) ... the fastest way to load a vertex from index key?

Tags: bigdata, orientdb, gremlin

Given a basic Blueprints-compatible OrientGraph with Index 'name' (unique or notunique), any suggestions for how the following could be improved, if needs be?

Note: I can't find a definitive guide to load a [blueprints] vertex using index. I have a large graph and using has('name','bob') (in console) takes 2 minutes!  On the other hand, an index-based search returns in milliseconds.

The best I've come up with so far:

```
OrientGraph graph = new OrientGraph("local:/graph1/databases/test", "admin", "admin");
List<ODocument> resultlist = graph.getRawGraph().query(new OSQLSynchQuery<ODocument>("SELECT FROM INDEX:name WHERE KEY = 'bob'"));
ODocument resultodoc = resultlist.get(0).field("rid");
String rid = resultodoc.getIdentity().toString();  // would return something like #6:1500000
Vertex v1 = graph.getVertex(rid);
System.out.println(v1.getProperty("name"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[OrientDB](http://www.orientdb.org) supports the [IndexableGraph](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/blob/master/blueprints-core/src/main/java/com/tinkerpop/blueprints/IndexableGraph.java) interface. To use it take a look at:

https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/Graph-Indices

Comment: Thanks again Lvca. It worked: `Index<Vertex> index = graph.getIndex("name", Vertex.class); Iterable<Vertex> results = index.get("name","bob"); Vertex v1 = results.iterator().next();`  ... I needed to create the index using Tinkerpop API (as opposed to executing SQL directly): `Index<Vertex> index = graph.createIndex("account_id", Vertex.class);`